# AWS EKS : Do I need to remove kube-dns before install external-dns?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-route53, kops, kube-dns, amazon-eks

I'am testing Amazon EKS and I'd like to know if I need to remove kube-dns if I'd like to use external-dns instead ?

Today I'am using KOPS to create K8S clusters in AWS. And I'am using the cluster-internal DNS server (kube-dns) with the flag `--watch-ingress=true` to automatically create route53 "hosts" regarding my Ingress annotations.

I'd like to reproduce this behavior with EKS and I see this project : https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/external-dns

But I don't know if if replaces kube-dns or if it works in addition of it.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

`kube-dns` is for DNS resolution inside the cluster. It doesn't interfere with external, public DNS resolution. So, don't delete `kube-dns`.

Kops' [`dns-controller` offers the `--watch-ingress` flag](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/blob/master/dns-controller/docs/flags.md), not `kube-dns`. Both the `dns-controller` & `external-dns` (Kubernetes incubator) can register public DNS names in AWS Route53.
[`external-dns` is aimed to replace `dns-controller` in the future](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/external-dns/issues/221).